How to get total count of orders from an append only order table?
I have an append only orders table that looks like
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT, 
    line_type VARCHAR(10),  -- Assuming 'line_type' values are short strings
    record_timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ
);

and has orders like so:
INSERT INTO orders (order_id, line_type, record_timestamp) VALUES (1, 'ordered', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO orders (order_id, line_type, record_timestamp) VALUES (1, 'shipped', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO orders (order_id, line_type, record_timestamp) VALUES (2, 'ordered', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO orders (order_id, line_type, record_timestamp) VALUES (2, 'ordered', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

The issue is that when an order changes from a status of "ordered" to "shipped", the old row is not deleted (insert only table). Thus in these cases we only want to count the "shipped" order. Of course if there is no "shipped" record for that order_id, then we want to include all the "ordered" records
SELECT COUNT(*), order_id FROM orders
group by order_id

This is wrong because it includes both the ordered and the shipped record for order_id 1. For order 2 it's of correct since there are no "shipped" record. It should be 1 for order id 1. And then if there are multiple shipped records it includes all of those (and no ordered records)
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/13197

I'm not sure if this is what you want to get or want to avoid: "And then if there are multiple shipped records it includes all of those". Anyway, does this help? https://dbfiddle.uk/9cDxRipE

I do want all shipped records OR all requested records if there is only one type. However if both types exist, I only want the shipped records. It looks like your fiddle does exactly that so thanks!

First if you want to get "the count of shipped orders grouped by order id" you can do:
SELECT o.order_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM orders o
WHERE o.line_type = 'shipped'
GROUP BY o.order_id;

But this won't include oders that does't contain any 'shipped' line_type, in your case this will return:



order_id
count




1
1



If you really want to get all order ids you must join your table on itself.

Base of the request

SELECT o1.order_id as o1_id, 
       o1.line_type as o1_lt, 
       o2.order_id as o2_id, 
       o2.line_type as o2_lt
FROM orders o1
       LEFT JOIN orders o2 ON (o1.order_id = o2.order_id
  AND o1.line_type = o2.line_type
  AND o2.line_type = 'shipped')
ORDER BY o1.order_id;

Note: you must LEFT JOIN to keep NULL values for o2
This will return:



o1_id
o1_lt
o2_id
o2_lt




1
ordered
NULL
NULL


1
shipped
1
shipped


2
ordered
NULL
NULL


2
ordered
NULL
NULL




The real request

Then you can apply the count function to the o2.order_id field grouping by o1.order_id (using the same join)
SELECT o1.order_id, COUNT(o2.order_id)
FROM orders o1
       LEFT JOIN orders o2 ON (o1.order_id = o2.order_id
  AND o1.line_type = o2.line_type
  AND o2.line_type = 'shipped')
GROUP BY o1.order_id
ORDER BY o1.order_id;

Then it will return all order_id that are at least once in orders table with the count of "shipped" line_type



order_id
count




1
1


2
0



See others examples:

How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?


thank you this works great. Is there way to do it without a join? Since it is such a large table I would like to avoid joining it to itself. Im thinking logically there should be a way - for each distinct order_id, if we only have "requested", sum those. If we have both, throw away the requested and only keep shipped... I was hoping some comination of group by to organize things by order_id and a window function to thow away the "requested" orders if there is a shipped one would be a possibility..
